# Can a Way Of The Sun Soul monk use Radiant Sun Bolt as the bonus attack for Martial Arts?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk

Can you use Radiant Sun Bolt as your bonus attack for Martial Arts?

> "When you use the Attack action with an unarmed strike or a monk weapon on your turn, you can make one unarmed strike as a bonus action."

For example, can I hit the guy then shoot a bolt at someone else?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**No.** By the rules, the Radiant Sun Bolt attack is a ranged spell attack, not an unarmed strike or monk weapon. You also can't replace one of your ki-fueled bolts with an unarmed attack.

That said, I don't see a big issue with letting it be used as if it was a monk weapon if your GM wants to house-rule it that way.

Answer (score 10):

No.

As you've already quoted, Martial Arts lets you make an *unarmed strike* as a bonus action. Radiant Sun Bolt is **not** an unarmed strike.

Furthermore, Radiant Sun Bolt is a ranged spell attack that can be used with the Attack action, not bonus action, and you can only use it as a bonus action if you're attacking with Radiant Sun Bolt and spend ki points.

> You gain a *ranged spell attack* that you can use with the Attack action. [...] When you use the Attack action on your turn to **use this special attack**, you can spend 1 ki point to make two additional attacks with it as a bonus action. (SCAG, pg.131)

Answer (score 5):

**No...** as a Monk who has 1 attack per Attack.  You cannot use RSB with a bonus action unless you attacked with it and spend 1 ki point to make 2 RSB attacks.  And you cannot make an unarmed strike as a bonus action after using RSB as your only attack because RSB is not a monk weapon.

**Yes, kind of...** as a 5th level Monk (or with extra attacks from another source).  With your attack action, you can spend one of your attacks to make a monk weapon attack or unarmed strike and the other to make this ranged spell attack.  This is an exception to the general rule.  Normally spell attacks can only be made with the Casting a Spell action, but this attack is specifically worded as being made with the Attack action.

[Jeremy Crawford's ruling allows mixing these attacks as part of the same Attack action.](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/666793638265950210)

If at least 1 of your attacks in your Attack action is with a monk weapon or an unarmed strike, you can use your bonus action to make a single unarmed strike. 
 If at least 1 of your attacks in your Attack action is a RSB, then you can spend 1 ki point to make 2 more RSB attacks with your bonus action.
If you used the Attack action on your turn, you make spend 1 ki point to use Flurry of Blows with your bonus action to make 2 unarmed attacks.

---

- MW : attack with a monk weapon
- US : unarmed strike
- RSB : Radiant Sun Bolt

### So monks with a single attack can:

- Attack: MW/US

  - Bonus:  US
  - Bonus:  2 US (Flurry for 1 ki after Attack)
- Attack: RSB

  - Bonus:  2 US (Flurry for 1 ki after Attack)
  - Bonus:  2 RSB (for 1 ki after using RSB in Attack)

### And monks with two attacks can:

- Attack: 2 MW/US

  - Bonus:  US
  - Bonus:  2 US (Flurry for 1 ki after Attack)
- Attack: 1 RSB and 1 MW/US (either order)

  - Bonus:  US
  - Bonus:  2 US (Flurry for 1 ki after Attack)
  - Bonus:  2 RSB (for 1 ki after using RSB in Attack)
- Attack: 2 RSB and 1 RSB/MW/US (either order)

  - Bonus:  2 US (Flurry for 1 ki after Attack)
  - Bonus:  2 RSB (for 1 ki after using RSB in Attack)

Answer (score 3):

The rule for Radiant Sun Bolt (XGTE p.35) says:

> You gain a new attack option that you can use with the Attack action.

It does not say "with an attack", it says "with the Attack action". The Attack action can only be used as an action, **not** as a bonus action.

So **No** you can't.

However:

> When you take the Attack action on your turn and use this special attack as part of it, you can spend 1 ki point to make the special attack twice as a bonus action

Meaning if you use Radiant Sun Bolt as part of an Attack action, then spending 1 ki point allows you to make the Radiant Sun Bolt twice more as a bonus action.

It says nothing about using Radiant Sun Bolt as a bonus action *in any other circumstances*, so you can't.