# Can I use Radiant Sun Bolt twice in one round?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk, actions

Can a Sun Soul monk use Radiant Sun bolt as an action and then again as a bonus action as well?

There's another question, [Can a Way Of The Sun Soul monk use Radiant Sun Bolt as the bonus attack for Martial Arts?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/76537/can-a-way-of-the-sun-soul-monk-use-radiant-sun-bolt-as-the-bonus-attack-for-mart), but it is about using Radiant Sun Bolt *once* after an unarmed attack, so it does not answer my question. I want to Radiant Sun Bolt a target as an action, then as a bonus action Radiant Sun Bolt the same target.

Answer (score 6):

This is specifically stated as something you *can* do *in the ability's description* as long as you have a ki point to spend. And what's more, you can make three attacks per turn with it:

> ## Radiant Sun Bolt
>
> You gain a ranged spell attack that you can use with the Attack action [...] When you use the Attack action on your turn *to use this special attack,* you can spend 1 ki point to **make two additional attacks with it as a bonus action.**

Comment: So it isn't 1 ki point per extra attack, it's just 1 ki= 2 more casts. Would that scale? like could you spend 2 ki points for more casts?

Comment: @TheFarm since utilising radiant sun bolt in this way requires a bonus action, and you can only take 1 bonus action each round, you cannot double up

Comment: It could be worth noting that from level 5, such a monk could even do four Radiant Sun Bolts per round: two through the Attack action (with Extra Attack), and two more through the mentioned bonus action.