# Way of the Sun Soul, Radiant Bolt clarification

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, attack, actions, monk

I'm struggling to interpret the way the rules are written for this monastic tradition, specifically this passage:

> When you take the Attack action on your turn and use this special attack as part of it, you can spend 1 ki point to make the special attack twice as a bonus action.

If I'm understanding this correctly, the monk must pick a target, use Attack action to throw a Radiant Sun Bolt, and then choose to burn both a Ki point and his bonus action to throw TWO additional bolts at the same target?

So with this, one could potentially throw 4 Radiant Sun Bolts at lvl 5 in one turn? (Attack+Attack+x2 Bonus)

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/94298/62294

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is correct. At level 5 the monk could use the Sun Bolt twice with Extra Attack, and then spend a Ki point to do it twice more. The description for the trait says:

> You gain a new attack option that you can use with the Attack action. This special attack is a ranged spell attack with a range of 30 feet. You are proficient with it, and you add your Dexterity modifier to its attack and damage rolls. Its damage is radiant, and its damage die is a d4. This die changes as you gain monk levels, as shown in the Martial Arts column of the Monk table.

Basically gives you a ranged punch option that deals radiant damage. At higher levels, this will be a good ranged option for Monks, as they don't have much in the way of range.

> When you take the Attack action on your turn and use this special attack as part of it, you can spend 1 ki point to make the special attack twice as a bonus action.
> When you gain the Extra Attack feature, this special attack can be used for any of the attacks you make as part of the Attack action.

When you take the Attack action and use Radiant Sun Bolt at least once, you can spend a Ki point to do a "flurry of blows" for the Radiant Sun Bolt.

Your inference was correct.